# Google Places JSON Parse

Tags: php, json

Im trying to get pull some reviews using the Google Places API. The JSON returns fine but no matter what approach I use, I can't get the foreach loop working to loop through the reviews.

I've tried using json_decode, setting it as an object, as an array...not sure what I am doing wrong and I'm sure it is something simple I am missing. I need a set of fresh eyes.

Here is a sample response using `file_get_contents` without `json_decode`.

```
{
"html_attributions":[
],
"result":{
"reviews":[
{
"author_name":"poiny 1965",
"author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106718355093949178742/reviews",
"language":"en",
"profile_photo_url":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-xLgQJ6zvmp8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACevoQO04SZnES1wQYg78lppVVHiQsyL3w/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
"rating":5,
"relative_time_description":"9 months ago",
"text":"Rick Lisek really knows his fishing!!! We limited out in the first hour of our trip. Amazing trip and so much fun. Best guide in Branson by FAR!",
"time":1524435416
},
{
"author_name":"advantage_ins01",
"author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/113907054087036345834/reviews",
"language":"en",
"profile_photo_url":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-SFLlNrrYyVU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/SlCw1_Yp1E0/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
"rating":5,
"relative_time_description":"a year ago",
"text":"We had a great experience on our fishing trip with Brandon Guided Fishing Tours! We all caught our limit, enjoyed Ricks company and knowledge. He went out of his way working with us to get out trip booked last minute. Five stars! We wouldn't hesitate to recommend Branson Guided fishing trips and especially Rick to any and all our friends.",
"time":1498171166
},
{
"author_name":"Anthony Dooley",
"author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/115423426947600048919/reviews",
"language":"en",
"profile_photo_url":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-SLuXMK30spw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACevoQPZPMXruClPBixUzfIApM0OR2DI6Q/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
"rating":5,
"relative_time_description":"2 years ago",
"text":"My 10 year old son and I went out with Rick's partner Ed this morning and had a great time. Both of us have very little fishing experience but had a blast. My son caught 8 trout and I caught 2 myself. Ed cleaned the fish for us at the end. He was very patient and made the trip very enjoyable for us despite the rain we had the whole time. Thanks Ed!",
"time":1464234004
},
{
"author_name":"Bennie Gremillion",
"author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/108824907367840034202/reviews",
"language":"en",
"profile_photo_url":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ZmopxEC956g/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACevoQPgxVj2fzLdl_mfSyd17i5-eK5O3g/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
"rating":5,
"relative_time_description":"a year ago",
"text":"My Wife and I fished trout on Lake Taneycomo with Ed Phillips, we had a great time. We caught our limit of trout in a very short time in the morning and released many more. Ed is a very experienced guide with lots of knowledge of the area. Rick was a pleasure to book a fishing trip with I called he replied with details in a message and voilà easy as that! I would recommend to them anyone.",
"time":1499288164
},
{
"author_name":"Charles Hancock",
"author_url":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/114897985775150327964/reviews",
"language":"en",
"profile_photo_url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZC86q9-joNI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACevoQOSfjR70RpQLkjBle_3NavGBvYLWg/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
"rating":5,
"relative_time_description":"2 years ago",
"text":"We have fished with Rick several times now and we always have a great time. He knows his stuff and we always catch fish. Our kids and family always rate this part of our vacations as the best experience. We will definitely be back and fish again.",
"time":1457924322
}
]
},
"status":"OK"
}
```

As an example, I tried the following:

```
<?php 
$results = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
foreach($results->result as $data) {
  foreach($data->reviews as $review) {
    echo $review->author_name;
  }
}
?>
```

This doesn't work for the second loop.

I also tried:

```
<?php 
$results = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
foreach($results->reviews as $key => $review) {
  echo $review->author_name;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this way with a single `foreach()` loop.

```
$results = json_decode($json);
foreach($results->result->reviews as $key=>$data) {
  echo $data->author_name.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Output:**

```
poiny 1965 
advantage_ins01
Anthony Dooley 
Bennie Gremillion 
Charles Hancock
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/XBDl7

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for that!

Comment: @RiotAct glad it helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can de-reference embedded objects in one shot by chaining names:

```
$results = json_decode(...);
foreach ($results->result->reviews as $review) {
    print_r($review);
}
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [author_name] => Charles Hancock
    [author_url] => https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/114897985775150327964/reviews
    [language] => en
    [profile_photo_url] => https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZC86q9-joNI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACevoQOSfjR70RpQLkjBle_3NavGBvYLWg/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg
    [rating] => 5
    [relative_time_description] => 2 years ago
    [text] => We have fished with Rick several times now and we always have a great time. He knows his stuff and we always catch fish. Our kids and family always rate this part of our vacations as the best experience. We will definitely be back and fish again.
    [time] => 1457924322
)
...
```